# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang during Java Game implementation

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

Please I'm trying to implement a game in Java with these rules...
You start the game from platform ‘0’ with 500 points.
• You jump to platform ‘1’. It is the first jump to that platform, so you’re going to have to pay the cost.
Points: 500 - 200 = 300
• You cannot jump to platform ‘2’ because it costs 400 points, but you only have 300. It is time to go
back. You jump to platform ‘0’. Points: 300 + 100 = 400.
• You jump to platform ‘1’. Points: 400 + 200 = 600
• After taking a detour, you finally have enough points to jump to platform '2', so you jump there.
Points: 600 - 400 = 200
• You jump to platform ‘3’. Points: 200 - 100 = 100

I have tried my implementation but it's not working..

Here is my Game.java file

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game("platforms.csv");
        game.run();


    }

    private Integer points = 500;
    private Platform activePlatform;
    private final String gameFile;

    public Game(String gameFile) {
        this.gameFile = gameFile;
    }

    public Platform findNextPlatform(Platform aPlatform) {
        List<Platform> allPlatforms = readPlatforms();

        if (points > aPlatform.getCost() ){
            points = points - aPlatform.getCost();
            System.out.println(allPlatforms.get(i + 1));
            aPlatform = allPlatforms.get(i + 1);
            return aPlatform;

        }
        else {
           aPlatform = allPlatforms.get(i-1);
           points = points + aPlatform.getCost();
           System.out.println(aPlatform);
           return aPlatform;
        }

//        return aPlatform;
    }
    int i = 0;
    public void run() {
        List<Platform> platforms = readPlatforms();

        // TODO: Implement your mighty algorithm and jump to oblivion.
        activePlatform = platforms.get(0);

        while (i < platforms.size()){

        Platform nextPlatform = findNextPlatform(activePlatform);
        jumpTo(nextPlatform);

        }
```

platforms.csv

```
index, cost
0, 100
1, 200
2, 400
3, 900
4, 100
```

Comment: what exactly is "not working"? Is there an exception? is the output wrong? Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: Yeah, my implementation is not working for some reasons... It's not jumping to the next platform after stating the conditions